C#'s NamedPipeClientStream gets 'Access to the path is denied" when server is Adminstrator and Client is user
Both server and client are running .NET Standard 2.1. The additional C# calls to deal with permissions seem missing. What's a common way of getting past this?
void CreatePipe()
 {
     if (m_bIsServer)
     {
         try
         {
             m_Pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(
                 m_szPipeName,
                 PipeDirection.InOut,
                 2, // max incoming instances
                 PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
                 PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
             Console.WriteLine("done creating pipe");
             m_szDebugName = "S:";
             m_bIsServer = true;

         }
         catch ( Exception e )
         {
             Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         m_Pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(
             ".",
             m_szPipeName,
             PipeDirection.InOut,
             PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
             System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation);
         m_szDebugName = "C:";
         m_bIsServer = false;
     }
 }


this is the only thing I've found that works simply: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NamedPipeServerStream.NetFrameworkVersion/

Use the PipeSecurity class by passing it to the constructor:
// Creates a PipeSecurity that allows users read/write access
PipeSecurity CreateSystemIOPipeSecurity()
{
    PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();

    var id = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);

    // Allow Everyone read and write access to the pipe. 
    pipeSecurity.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(id, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

    return pipeSecurity;
} 

Use that function when creating the pipe:
PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = CreateSystemIOPipeSecurity();
pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName,
                                       PipeDirection.InOut,
                                       1,
                                       PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                                       PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
                                       0x4000,
                                       0x400,
                                       pipeSecurity,
                                       HandleInheritability.Inheritable);

P. S. Below is my solution for MemoryMappedFile. It can be applied to named pipes.
The easiest way is to set access for Everyone:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetSecurityInfo", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern uint SetSecurityInfoByHandle(SafeHandle handle, uint objectType, uint securityInformation,
byte[]? owner, byte[]? group, byte[]? dacl, byte[]? sacl);

then
// mmfile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("Global\\jdfghdfghsd", requiredsize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
// use handle for the named pipe instead of mmfile.SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle
if (SetSecurityInfoByHandle(mmfile.SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle, 1, 4, null, null, null, null) != 0)
    throw new Exception("MemoryMappedFile set security failed");


PipeSecurity doesn't exist in NetStandard 2.1 that I know of. Plus that version of the constructor doesn't exist.

Added my solution with using of Windows API from MemoryMappedFileSecurity missing in .NET 6.

not surprised it doesn't work. Don't know if it's your code, or just doesn't work for named pipes.

I suppose it should work. SetSecurityInfoByHandle sets security for any object including named pipes. The named pipe created under administrative account needs to be available for users with read (and write, if nedeed) permission. Did you get the same error?

It's my solution and I spent 2 days searching Internet to find it. Did you try to run your client under administrative account? Does it work?

Did you try other TokenImpersonationLevel values?

Named Pipe Security and Access Rights --> SetSecurityInfo
